# WCF for MetaWeblog

Tags: wcf, web-services, api, blogs, metaweblog

I'm trying to find a really good example for implementing the MetaWeblog API using a WCF service. I can't seem to clear my head and think of a clean way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a reasonable start, [wfc-for-metaweblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/clemensv/archive/2009/04/03/xml-rpc-with-wcf-updated.aspx).

Comment: This is a complete WCF implementation of Metaweblog. Perhaps you should restate your questions if you aren't looking for a WCF/metaweblog implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly WCF-related, but [octalforty Syndication](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-syndication/) has a nice type-safe [IMetaWeblogService](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-syndication/source/browse/trunk/octalforty.Syndication.Blogging/MetaWeblog/IMetaWeblogService.cs) definition and all related objects you can use as a base for your further studies.

Comment: Thanks, not WCF, but might be useful.